# Iterating over a for loop X amount of times from textfield input

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I am trying to query my textfield.text input (Let's say the user types 5 in the keypad).

Then convert the string to an integer.

Then make a `for` loop and run the `for` loop X amount of times. (X being the integer converted from the string).

I have tried the below however I can't work out the syntax/format for the for loop.

```
var shotCountInt = Int(numberOfShots.text!)

for item in 0..<shotCountInt {
     //do something
}
```

The error I am getting is on the for loop which is:

> Type 'Int?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: A `UITextField` doesn't keep track of how many times its been edited. You would need to make a subclass that extends it to have such functionality. What exactly constitutes an "edit"?

Comment: According  to your code It should be binary operator '0..<' can't be applied to operands of type Int and Int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in `0..<shotCountInt` of optional **Int** , so

```
if let shotCountInt = Int(numberOfShots.text!) {
    for item in 0..<shotCountInt { 
       // proceed here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, since it is correct that `shotCountInt` (in the question) is optional and therefore cannot be a range bound.

Comment: @robmayoff My suspicion (not my vote) is that the answer was posted before the question issue was properly clarified and the answer comes across as a guess (which turns out to be correct). I suggest the first line of the answer be edited now that we know the actual issue and maybe the down voter will reverse their vote.

Comment: @robmayoff also it's strange how op sees his attached error for this problem above i commented what he may encounter